# Reputation for new users

Tags: support, reputation

I was trying to understand how the reputation works and I don't quite get it. It is not the first time, that I see users who ask their first question, don't have other activities (like answering questions) and having 100+ reputation. Is transferred from other websites like stackoverflow?

Comment: Extra 100 is only awarded to the *StackExchange Rich and Powerful Elite (tm)* ;-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of.

Reputation isn't shared between sites, but once you've earned 200 reputation on one SE site, you automatically receive an "[association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/238438)" of 100 reputation on any SE site.
This includes sites you are already a part of ([including the site where you earned the 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90687/238438)), and sites you join later.